# Hide buttons on the page by special attribute Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm new in web. I have such table:

```
<tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.DateStart.ToShortDateString()
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.DateEnd.ToShortDateString()
                </td>
                <td data-name="@item.Id" data-approved="@item.Approved.ToString()">
                    @item.Approved.ToString()
                </td>                
                <td>
                    @item.FirstName.ToString() @item.LastName.ToString()
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Position.ToString()
                </td>

                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary accept-button" data-id="@item.Id">Accept</button>               
                    <button class="btn btn-danger decline-button" data-id="@item.Id"> Decline</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

And I wrote a script for buttons on this page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#requestTable').DataTable(
        {
            aoColumns: [
            { mDataProp: "DateStart", sTitle: "Date Start" },
            { mDataProp: "DateEnd", sTitle: "Date End" },
            { mDataProp: "Approved", sTitle: "Approved" },
            { mDataProp: "Data", sTitle: "Employee" },
            { mDataProp: "Position", sTitle: "Position" },
            { mDataProp: "", sTitle: "" }
            ],
            columnDefs: [{
                targets: 'no-sort',
                orderable: false
            }]
        });

    $('button.accept-button').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id')
        var appr = $('td[data-name="' + id + '"]');
        appr[0].textContent = "True";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/TableRequest/AcceptRequest",
            data: { 'id': id },
            success: function (msg) {
            }
        });
    });
    var tempId;
    $('button.decline-button').click(function () {
        tempId = $(this).attr('data-id')
        var appr = $('td[data-name="' + tempId + '"]');
        appr[0].textContent = "False";
        $("#dialog").dialog()
    });
    $('button.ok-request').click(function () {
        var message = $('textarea#commentForDecline').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/TableRequest/DeclineRequest",
            data: { 'message': message, 'id': tempId },
            success: function (msg) {
            }
        });
        $("#dialog").dialog('close');
        $('textarea#commentForDecline').val('');
    });

    hideButtons();

}); 
function hideButtons(){
        // var appr = $('td[data-name="' + id + '"]');
       var appr = $("td[data-approved='false']");
       var 
       if(appr[0].textContent == "True")
       {
           $('button.accept-button').hide();
       }
       if(appr[0].textContent == "False")
       {
           $('button.decline-button').hide();
       }
    };
```

I wanna to hide buttons in depends on `Approved` field in the table. If `@item.Approved.ToString()` is true - need to hide butto "accept", else - "decline". Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can hide with $(selector).hide() and show with $(selector).show();

Comment: I need to do it for all buttons on the page. I have a table with many buttons. When I click to any button - value will change and I should hide this button and show another.

Comment: Yeah.  $('button').on('click', function(){ /* change the value */ $(this).hide();  $(otherButtonSelector).show(); });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td>
@if (item.Approved)
{              
    <button class="btn btn-danger decline-button" data-id="@item.Id"> Decline</button>
}
else
{
    <button class="btn btn-primary accept-button" data-id="@item.Id">Accept</button> 
}
</td>
```

I assumed that item.Approved is a boolean. If not you have to alter the if-clause.

Comment: Thanks, it's really easy solution. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using:

```
$('td[data-approved=true]').nextAll('td').find('button.accept-button').hide();

$('td[data-approved!=true]').nextAll('td').find('button.decline-button').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add "ButtonApproved" + item.approved.toString() as one of the classes on your buttons and then do a $(".ButtonApprovedFalse").hide().
Or else define the "ButtonApprovedFalse" class as hidden.
Since you are not using that as a class anywhere else, only the buttons that are "not approved" will get hidden.
When you click on a button to Unapprove it, just add the class "ButtonApprovedFalse" to that button: $(this).AddClass("ButtonApprovedFalse").